# How to associate a group to a host with Ansible Tower / AWX REST api?

Tags: rest, post, ansible-awx

I am able to create a host in AWX with the REST API but haven't found out how to associate that host to a group via the REST api.  (The groups have already been created via the GUI).  Wondering how to add the group to the host via the REST API.
*using python:*

```
PAYLOAD = {
    'name': "myHost",
    'inventory': "myInventory",
    'description': "This is my awesome host."
    }

r = requests.post(url=host_URL, data=json.dumps(PAYLOAD), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Never found out how to do this with the REST API.  Did it easily enough with tower-cli

1) Find out what your group ids are:

```
tower-cli group list -a -i yourinventoryname
```

2) Add the host to the group:

```
tower-cli host associate --host 10.1.2.103 --group 4
```